# Transport operation on $\Sigma$-types in cubical type theory

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

In Exercise 4.3 of "Cubical Methods in Homotopy Type Theory and Univalent Foundations'',
It sais that we run into problems when we try to define computation rules for transport operation on $\Sigma$ types.

However, I didn't run into any problem (Maybe I'm misunderstanding something). How about the following one?

For
$\Gamma, i:\mathbf{I}\vdash (x:A)\times B$
and
$\Gamma\vdash p:(x:A[0/i])\times B[0/i]$,
we define
$$\Gamma\vdash \mathrm{transport}^i ((x:A)\times B) \hspace{0.3em} p
= \langle
    \mathrm{transport^i A\hspace{0.3em} p.1},
    \mathrm{transport}^i (B[\mathrm{transport}^jA[i\wedge j]\hspace{0.3em}p.1/x])\hspace{0.3em} p.2
  \rangle.
$$

I think this type checks, and the key idea is that we use a connection.

Comment: What you wrote does work. Perhaps it just meant that it is not quite as simple as the non-dependent cases.